# Replace the image on one pod manually, while other pods uses the main image

Tags: kubernetes, dockerfile, canary-deployment

Let's say I have 10 pods running a stable version, and I wish to replace the image of one of them to run a newer version before a full rollout.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 3):

Not as such: every pod managed by a Deployment is expected to be identical, including running the same image.  You can't change a pod's image once it's been created, and if you change the Deployment's image, it will try to recreate all of its managed pods.

If the only thing you're worried about is the pod starting up, the [default behavior of a deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#updating-a-deployment) is to start 25% of its specified replicas with the new image.  The old pods will continue running uninterrupted until the new replicas successfully start and pass their readiness checks.  If the new pods immediately go into CrashLoopBackOff state, the old pods will still be running.

If you want to start a pod specifically as a canary deployment, you can create a second Deployment to handle that.  You'll need to include some label on the pods (for instance, `canary: 'true'`) where you can distinguish the canary from main pods.  This would be present in the pod spec, and in the deployment selector, but it would not be present in the corresponding Service selector: the Service matches both canary and non-canary pods.  If this runs successfully then you can remove the canary Deployment and update the image on the main Deployment.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer mentioned, It sounds like you are talking about a canary deployment. You can do this with Kubernetes and also with Istio. I prefer Istio as it gives you some great control over traffic weighting. I.e you could send 1% of traffic to the canary and 99% to the control. Great for testing in production. It also lets you route using HTTP headers.

https://istio.io/latest/blog/2017/0.1-canary/

If you want to do it with k8s just create two deployments with unique deployment names (myappv1 & myappv2 for example) with the same app= label. Then you can just create a service with the selector = whatever your app label is. The svc will round robin between the two v1 and v2 deployments.